# Why ActivityIndicator changes state after entire method is completed?

Tags: xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I would like to show ActivityIndicator object after user tap the login button on page. Unfortunately there is small problem to do that because it seems like ActivityIndicator change state after entire method is completed. This is code I wrote so far:

```
private void Login(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    BusyIndicator.IsVisible = true; //<- here I want to show indicator

    try
    {
        //some input validation, connection opening etc
        ConnectionHandler.OpenConnection(ServerIP, "dmg", false);


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logging.Error(e.Message, "Connection", e);
    }
}
```

When I set breakpoint after `BusyIndicator.IsVisible = true;` there is absolutely no change in app. However I noticed that when method is completed then indicator is shown. Is this a correct behavior of this control?

Why I need this? Because field validation and connecting with server takes some time and I need to show to user that something happens in background. Login function takes ~1 sec so indicator show and hide quickly I can't even see any change.

How can I show indicator immediately after user tap a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Login() method is being executed in the UI thread. So, despite setting `BusyIndicator.IsVisible = true;`, the thread continues tio execute the method to get data, so the UI does not respond.

Solution, run the  OpenConnection in a different thread:

```
private async void Login(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    BusyIndicator.IsVisible = true; //<- here I want to show indicator

    try
    {
        //some input validation, connection opening etc


        await Task.Run(() => { ConnectionHandler.OpenConnection(ServerIP, "dmg", false);});
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logging.Error(e.Message, "Connection", e);
    }
}
```